# Merge/Append IEnumerable Objects

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
Assembly MyAssembly = null; 
    MyAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(APath, @"A.B.Database.dll"));
    System.Type MyElement  = MyAssembly.GetType("A.B.Database.C"); 
    object MyElementAr = MyAssembly.GetType("A.B.Database.D");                       
    object MyElementAr2 = MyAssembly.GetType("A.B.Database.E");                       

        var collection1 = (IEnumerable)MyElementAr;
        var collection2 = (IEnumerable)MyElementAr2;
```

In the above code i want to append collection 1 and collection 2 to collection3.

How can i go about it as the below statements return an error.

```
var collection3 = collection1 + collection 2;
```

Also concat method is not available for below.

```
var collection3 =  collection1.concat(collection 2); // concat not available.
```

Comment: Try: `var coll3 = coll1.Cast<object>().Concat(coll2.Cast<object>());`

Comment: Cast is probably the way to go. But beware of incompatibles types which may throw exceptions. Use a common base type for "coll" in @pwas example. Also, "Concat" is Uppercase and requires System.Linq.

Comment: I think you should include the `System.Linq` namespace and use the `Concat`-method (camelcase), since `collection1` is already an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do. `MyElementAr` is a `Type`, you can't cast it to `IEnumerable`. Do you just want to create a collection that contains `MyElementAr` and `MyElementAr2`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? You are getting three types by name but it isn't clear what you then want to do since you don't have any `IEnumerable` objects... Not least of which is the confusion that `MyElement` is never used again...

Comment: @Caramiriel the type is `IEnumerable` (non generic) - there is no extension methods in `System.Linq` - that is why hee needs to cast it first.

Comment: @pwas: Ah, I didn't know there was no non-generic variants of the extension methods available. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: @pwas . Bang on target. Thank you very much !! This solved it for me .

Answer (score -4):

As mentioned by @pwas in the comment, the answer is

```
var coll3 = coll1.Cast<object>().Concat(coll2.Cast<object>());
```

Comment: this is kinda pointless. why not just `new []{ MyElementAr, MyElementAr2 }` ? And how does that code even work, you can't cast Type to IEnumerable. maybe you didn't get a compile-time error but surely it will blow up at runtime.